# Why using string[] args in all main methods?

Tags: c#, methods, entry-point

I'm a beginner in learning programming. I ask about using the string array in main method as a parameter. Why not writing the Main()  method without the string array? What is the point of having this array in Main method?

For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
}
```

Comment: cause that's how everyone else does it (except win32 winMain for some reason)

Comment: As you can add multiple parameters there

Comment: See http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html

Answer (score 19):

Console applications predate GUI applications, and these take command-line parameters for very long time (at least from CP/M time, which preceded MS-DOS, which preceded Windows, which preceded Windows NT — all preserving more or less the same logic).

You can pass command-line parameters to Windows GUI apps, too.

These are the `args`.

Comment: This is essentially it. The underlying system is almost always something like a command line. I don't know of any systems that don't let you pass arguments in this way. Windows shortcuts, for instance, specifically allow this.

Comment: In addition to adding the ability to open files using a flag you can also add support to enable debug/logging for tests or pipe data in/out of an application if necessary.

Comment: Actually this is older than that. Unix already uses it in C, with its `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`.

Comment: @mouviciel: Obviously it is older than that (and probably older than Unix). The original question is tagged with `c#`, so it's [mostly] about Windows, and Windows's lineage starts with CP/M and does not cross with Unix.

Comment: @Craig: I'm aware of the NT heritage; inside, Windows is a much nicer OS that one might think looking at the various 'surface-level' APIs. But this applies to the kernel architecture, not (so much) the userland. Obviously, MS had to support the previous convention of invoking things like `foo /h` that people were used to.

Comment: @9000 Replacing my prev comment to correct the spelling of DEC/VAX. Good grief.  ;-)

Comment: That's not really true. ;-) Windows NT (Windows 8.1 is the latest version of Windows NT) comes from a DEC/VAX heritage, not CP/M, and borrows plenty from UNIX, with the older Win32 API plastered onto it, alongside other API's like POSIX and, originally, OS/2 Presentation Manager. And now you can add the Metro/Modern UI API. But either way, Windows NT was a serious departure and was only able to run legacy Windows 16-bit (and now 32-bit) applications through a WoW (Windows on Windows) emulation layer and pointer thunking.

Comment: @9000 Windows is a very nice operating system underneath. Of course, Windows versions since Vista run device drivers outside the kernel, so that's changed since the original NT days. It's kind of a beautiful thing to see a video driver crash, and see the OS unload and reload it instead of halting irreparably. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This is **not** the sole province of "old" console (command line) applications. Every running program has a "command line" that points at the executable image and includes any command line parameters. Plenty of GUI apps take arguments that alter either their initialization behavior or runtime behavior or both.

Most languages do let you specify an entry-point function that takes no arguments. But virtually all of them also allow you to pass arguments. This `args` array is simply an ordered collection of whatever is passed on the command line after the name of the executable file when the program is executed. **EDIT:** And of course in the case of the C language (as one example), the first argument (index 0) is actually the name of the program.

For example, imagine a pointless little program that displays a message in a message box, and lets you specify the message and the title for the window on the command line, like this:

`myprogram.exe -title Foo -message Bar`

Your args array in this case will look like this, presuming a language like C# which does not include the program name in the `args` array:

```
args[ 0 ] = "-title"
args[ 1 ] = "Foo"
args[ 2 ] = "-message"
args[ 3 ] = "Bar"
```

Making sense of the order of the arguments, and which ones are valid or not, is totally up to your own application code.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Generally, args[0] is the full executable path of the program itself. in this case, args[1] would be "-title", etc  At least for C, and I assume it to be the same for other languages. See http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html

Comment: It's not generally the same for other languages. The question specifically asked about c#, which does not include the executable name in args (which is available via System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly instead).

Comment: @Mawg `argc` in C may be zero. in case of non-zero `argc`, `argv[0]` shall be a string that represents the "program name", or an empty string if the name is not available from the host environment. There is no requirement anywhere that it shall be a "full executable path". This is all from C99 section 5.1.2.2.1. Even your non-normative URL says this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever listed items in a directory using

```
ls -a ~/Downloads
```

or

```
dir C:\Users\user1\Downloads\ /P
```

Now those "ls" and "dir" are commands/programs and the latter arguments are passed to the programs as `string[] argv` or sometimes `int argc, char** argv`. They provide arguments to the programs so they can behave accordingly.

When you start a program the OS loads the program to the memory and pushes the arguments to the stack. Now they are available to the program to be used.

High-level languages give you an easy way to access those arguments on the stack (as string arrays or an array of pointers to null terminated strings). If you used assembly, you would need to do some pointer arithmetic and load the arguments from stack to registers when you needed them.

For more details checkout following link, good explanation: [FreeBSD Command Line Arguments](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-command-line.html)

Comment: this seems to merely repeat points made and explained in [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/264919/312600) and especially [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/264941/31260) prior answer

Comment: @gnat Thank you for the feedback, but I think how you say something is also as important as what you say. I made the same point differently.